# Keyboard and mouse not working on Ubuntu 18.04.4 after installing CUDA 10.0 with Autoware 1.13.0

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, display, cuda

I have installed Autoware 1.13.0 by using the source. First, I have installed Ros Melodic and CUDA 10.2 and tried to build the Autoware and it failed. Then, I realized CUDA 10.0 is needed.

I have uninstalled CUDA 10.2 and reinstalled CUDA 10.0. Everything was installed perfectly and all GPU tests passed.

After that, I hit reboot and after my PC rebooted, my keyboard and mouse are not responding.

I have Ubuntu 18.04.4 on my PC.

Please help on how to fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I got stuck in the same place while recently updating from CUDA 10.0 to 10.1. The issue is caused by missing Xorg drivers for inputs. I am not sure how this happened. It is possible that when you remove `cuda` and then follow-up with `autoremove` it uninstalls some xorg packages.

The solution that worked for me is to reinstall xorg-input package:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all
```

I hope this helps the OP and anyone looking for a solution to this problem.

NOTE: Since your input devices are no longer active it is not possible to install from default UI. However, during boot, you can select `Ubuntu (recovery) mode` using `Advanced boot options` in the `grub` menu. From here one can continue `normal boot` which allows the installation of required files. Ensure the system is connected to the network.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

please download CUDA 10.0 from Nvidia as well as choice network install type.

Comment: Can you explain where to download CUDA 10.0 - how to install - and how to choose the type of install?